# "Красно-оранжевый" - когда так написано, то как понять, один это цвет или их сочетание?

Tags: значение-слов

Только из контекста? Если будет написано, например, "двухцветный, красно-оранжевый..."
А если просто: "На опушке стоял серо-зеленый дом". Он серый, но с зеленой крышей, ставнями и проч.? Или он все-таки весь серо-зеленый? Без уточнения не понять?

Answer (score 2):

Красно-оранжевый (и т. п.) - это в большинстве случаев, как в быту, так и в технике (там это может быть о положении в спектре), об *оттенке* цвета. Альтернативное понимание (как *сочетание* отдельных цветов) держится на условностях контекста или традиции и может быть ясным без уточнений, например: "бело-голубые" - о сочетании цветов в форме спортсменов; "жёлто-зелёный" провод - о двуцветной изоляции провода заземления; "красно-коричневые" - о союзе политических сил, каждую из которых символизирует свой цвет и т. д. В ситуации неясности, как с "домом", для уточнения достаточно сказать "**серо-зелёного цвета**" либо "**серый с зелёным**".